# Print the first value of a dataframe based on condition, then iterate to the next sequence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking to perform data analysis on 100-years of climatological data for select U.S. locations (8 in particular), for each day spanning the 100-years.  I have a `pandas dataFrame` set up with columns for Max temperature, Min temperature, Avg temperature, Snowfall, Precip Total, and then Day, Year, and Month values (then, I have an index also based on a date-time value).  Right now, I want to set up a for loop to print the first Maximum temperature of 90 degrees F or greater from each year, but ONLY the first.  Eventually, I want to narrow this down to each of my 8 locations, but first I just want to get the for loop to work.

Experimented with various iterations of a for loop.

```
for year in range(len(climate['Year'])):    
           if (climate['Max'][year] >=90).all():
                print (climate.index[year])
                break
```

Unsurprisingly, the output of the loop I provided prints the first 90 degree day period (from the year 1919, the beginning of my data frame) and breaks.

```
for year in range(len(climate['Year'])):    
           if (climate['Max'][year] >=90).all():
                print (climate.index[year])
                break
```

1919-06-12 00:00:00

That's fine.  If I take out the break statement, all of the 90 degree days print, including multiple in the same year.  I just want the first value from each year to print.  Do I need to set up a second for loop to increment through the year?  If I explicitly state the year, ala below, while trying to loop through a counter, the loop still begins in 1919 and eventually reaches an out of bounds index.  I know this logic is incorrect.

```
count = 1919

while count < 2019:
    for year in range(len(climate['Year'])):    
        if (climate[climate['Year']==count]['Max'][year] >=90).all():
                print (climate.index[year])
                count = count+1
```

Any input is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this without having a second for loop. Assuming the `climate` dataframe is ordered chronologically, this should do what you want:

```
current_year = None
for i in range(climate.shape[0]):
    if climate['Max'][i] >= 90 and climate['Year'][i] != current_year:
        print(climate.index[i])
        current_year = climate['Year'][i]
```

Notice that we're using the `current_year` variable to keep track of the latest year that we've already printed the result for. Then, in the if check, we're checking if we've already printed a result for the year of the current row in the loop.

That's one way to do it, but I would suggest taking a look at [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) because I think it fits your use case well. You could get a dataframe that contains the first >=90 max days per year with the following (again assuming `climate` is ordered chronologically):

```
climate[climate.Max >= 90].groupby('Year').first()
```

This just filters the dataframe to only contain the >=90 max days, groups rows from the same year together, and retains only the first row from each group. If you had an additional column `Location`, you could extend this to get the same except per location per year:

```
climate[climate.Max >= 90].groupby(['Location', 'Year']).first()
```

Comment: The .first() function is fantastic.  Exactly what I needed (and I can split it out via 'City' to get the except per location).  I'm embarrassed I did not find this sooner but I am extremely grateful you took the time to point this out, thank you!

Comment: May I just ask, with the for loop you provided, I've been running into the same issue I was also having with some of my previous for loops:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Do I need to place .all() after the column call?  The columns are all made of integers with no missing values.

Comment: Interesting, I was a little confused as to why you had that `.all()` there in your loop. Is the type of `climate['Max'][i]` not just an int? That error seems to suggest that `climate['Max'][i]` is a `pd.Series`.

Comment: The loop works fine for me on this simple example: `climate = pd.DataFrame({ 'Max': [91, 92, 92], 'Year': [2019, 2019, 2020], 'Month': [4, 4, 4], 'Day': [1, 2, 3]})`.

Comment: Your example data frame works for me too.  'Max' and 'Year' are dtype int32.  Yet I cannot get the loop to work without adding .all() or .any(), which I suspect is taking the loop an extra long time to process.  Maybe it's just something with the data I'm using (or the vast amount of it).  Frustrating, but I should be able to work around it.